# First parameter in Vue.set() method

Tags: vue.js

Please help me understand below problem:

1. From https://alligator.io/vuejs/common-gotchas/

"You can’t add new properties to the root data object directly, but you can use":

> Vue.set(this.data, ‘propname’, value)

2. From https://blog.cloudboost.io/reactivity-in-vue-js-2-vs-vue-js-3-dcdd0728dcdf

> Vue.set(this.$data,'lastAddedName','John Elway');

But first parameter in Vue.set() above method: "this.data" or "this.$data", it's root data object, so an error throws in console. So docs above are wrong or I misunderstood?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean by "You can’t add new properties to the root data object directly" is that adding a property using the key/value assignment method doesn't create a reactive object; no getter and setter are being created and changes to it will not propagate to any use of that property.

<s>`Vue.set` on the other hand was written specifically to create properties with the correct getters and setters in place allowing vue to continue running without properties being hidden from the reactive layer.</s>

The way they're using `Vue.set` is incorrect and Vue will not set the value on the vue instance itself; it also throws a warning in development mode.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method (Official Vue.js docs). 

So, "this.data" or "this.$data" throw error in console. You can check: https://jsfiddle.net/vx89888v/

Comment: Looking through the commit history of vue on github it seems that they fixed it so that it returns the value instead of setting it. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank **@Justin MacArthur**. I'll contact them and feedback.